# Are SGX-listed US-domiciled ETFs held by a non-resident non-citizen of the US subject to US Estate Tax?

Tags: singapore, estate-tax

These ETFs are listed on the Singapore Exchange (SGX) with a "US domicile"<sup>1</sup>:

1. SPDR® Dow Jones® Industrial Average ETF Trust (D07)
2. SPDR® Gold Shares (O87)
3. SPDR® S&P 500® ETF Trust (S27)

If these are held by a non-resident non-citizen of the US in a Singapore-based brokerage account (e.g. brokerage offered by one of the big Singapore banks) or held in a Supplementary Retirement Scheme (SRS) brokerage account, upon the account holder's death would these be considered "U.S.-situated assets" such that amounts above USD60k be subject to Estate Tax<sup>2</sup>?

Links:

1. https://www.ssga.com/sg/en/individual/etfs/fund-finder
2. https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/some-nonresidents-with-us-assets-must-file-estate-tax-returns